# Match smilies without spaces in WordPress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I know, it's dumb, but I think it's annoying that when someone enters a smiley manually like this hi:) it will not be detected and converted by WordPress because WordPress smilies functions looks for spaces and require a space before and after the smiley replacement.

I searched but I couldn't find a helpful topic about this, does anyone have any workaround for this? Like automatically replacing smilies text with [space]:)[space] upon post/comment post so it would be detected?

Here's WordPress expression to match smilies:

`/((?:\s|^)\|(?:_\|)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)x(?:D)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)o(?:_O)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)\^(?:\^â€™|\^â€˜|\^'|\^’)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)X(?:D)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)O(?:_o)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)\>(?:\:D|\:\(|\-I)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)\=(?:\^\-\^\=)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)\<(?:3)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^);(?:\-\)|\))(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)\:(?:â€™\(|â€˜\(|\||x|wink\:|whiterussian\:|twisted\:|star\:|smile\:|shock\:|sad\:|roll\:|razz\:|p|oops\:|o|neutral\:|mrgreen\:|martini\:|mad\:|lol\:|idea\:|heart\:|grin\:|facepalm\:|evil\:|eek\:|developer\:|cry\:|cool\:|burrito\:|bear\:|arrow\:|\\|X|P|O|D|\?\?\?\:|\?\:|\?|\/|\-\||\-x|\-p|\-o|\-\\|\-X|\-P|\-O|\-D|\-\?|\-\/|\-\)|\-\(|\)|\(|'\(|’\(|\!\:)(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)8(?:O|\-O|\-\))(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)\((?:w\)|W\))(?=\s|$))|((?:\s|^)&(?:lt;3|gt;\:D|gt;\:\(|gt;\-I)(?=\s|$))/m`

Comment: You might want to ask this on the [Wordpress SE site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) instead. **:)**

Comment: I did, but looks like nobody is there.. :) I edited my question with WordPress regex expression used to match smilies if it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question is simple, just make sure you remove the `\s` character from the above string (or what generates it).

Comment: I wonder if there's any unforeseen issues with removing spaces from the smilies regex.. i'm thinking there might be false positives crop up.

Comment: I think so too because WordPress added spaces intentionally. I'll test it for a while...